# Analyzing the OFDM out-of-band effect when using different guard interval

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

I am trying to understand the concept of out-of-band (OOB) which occur with  OFDM, I have tried to read about it, but I couldn’t understand how I can illustrate that effect with MATLB.

This is the matlab code I am using:

```
clc; clear; 
% Parameters
fft_size = 64;      % FFT size
cp_length = 16;     % Length of cyclic prefix
num_symbols = 1;    % Number of OFDM symbols
fs = 1000;          % Sampling frequency (Hz)
symbol_length = fft_size + cp_length;  %The symbols length

% Create a simple OFDM symbol with a single subcarrier
data_symbol = [1, zeros(1, fft_size - 1)];  % Single active subcarrier

% Repeat the symbol to create multiple symbols
data_symbols = repmat(data_symbol, num_symbols, 1);

% Perform CP-OFDM modulation
ofdm_symbols_cp = ifft(data_symbols);

% Add cyclic prefix
ofdm_symbols_with_cp = [ofdm_symbols_cp(end - cp_length + 1:end), ofdm_symbols_cp];

% Calculate the frequency spectrum of the CP-OFDM signal
ofdm_spectrum_cp = fft(ofdm_symbols_with_cp);

% Create the frequency axis
f_cp = (-symbol_length/2 : symbol_length/2 - 1) / symbol_length * fs;

% Plot the frequency spectrum of CP-OFDM
figure;
plot(f_cp, abs(fftshift(ofdm_spectrum_cp))); hold on; 


% Zero padding
ofdm_symbols_zp = [ofdm_symbols_cp, zeros(1,cp_length)];

% Calculate the frequency spectrum of ZP-OFDM
ofdm_spectrum_zp = fft(ofdm_symbols_zp);

% Create the frequency axis
f_zp = (-symbol_length/2 : symbol_length/2 - 1) / symbol_length * fs;

% Plot the frequency spectrum of ZP-OFDM
plot(f_zp, abs(fftshift(ofdm_spectrum_zp)), 'r'); hold on;
title('CP-OFDM and ZP-OFDM Frequency Spectrum');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Magnitude');
legend('CP-OFDM','ZP-OFDM')
grid on;
```

I got the following result:

### [image]

My concern, Why the figure is not square window as I usually see in other books? For example the following figure:

[image]